# create a new page in odoo -11 theme

Tags: page-layout, odoo-11

I am following the odoo-11 documentation - https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/themes.html#create-a-specific-page-layout
  and trying to create a page layout. But It shows error. I have no idea  why this error pop out. I am newbie.

```
> Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 646, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 307, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 332, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 927, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 928, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 916, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-45>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 71, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 600, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 539, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 85, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 242, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 94, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 788, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 836, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3560, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src/lxml/etree.c:194584)
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: template, line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear indicates you traceback

```
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 836, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3560, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src/lxml/etree.c:194584)
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: template, line 5
```

Your created new template had bugs not properly coded html tempalte